# Discord.js components

Tags: node.js, discord, components

I wonder if there is a way I can send components in a channel on discord.js, I know there is other libraries for the buttons, but I want to know a way to send any component included in here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components is there a way?

I have already tried the example of the "Select Menus", but it seems that discordjs doesn't recognize "components" as a property/ignores them in the ".send({})"

[This is what I mean by "ignores components" since if I send that it will just send the content but not the actual component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL0kU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, for now this is only usable in discord.js dev branch. Version 13 will have this feature.